# Find and replace values of all 'a' target in a DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to scan through a page and replace or insert every single 'a' link with this:

```
target='_self'
```

My question is, should I use regular expressions, method find() or some other method for this? I'm really new to js so I'm still trying to find out many of the various methods or possibilities.

Any suggestion or tips are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` to get the list of all the `<a>` tags.

Comment: FYI, since you're new to javascript, you should familiarize yourself with jQuery. It makes DOM manipulation like this so much easier IMO. It's well documented too.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the reply, after I get all the 'a' elements, what should I do to replace or insert the target=_self attribute?  thanks

Comment: Check the answer from lolol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');
 }
```

Update:

w3c recommends to directly access a attribute when it is available (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes) so the best way to go is:

```
  anchors[i].target = '_self';
```

Comment: this looks perfect, just one last thing what if the current 'a' already has a target=_top attribute, will this overwrite it or do I need to first remove it before applying this. thanks

Answer (score 3):

if using jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function(){ $(this).attr("target", "_self"); });
```

Without:

```
var allAs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<allAs.length;i++){ 
     allAs[i].target =  "_self"; 
}
```

Comment: It is correct: target DOMString Reflects the target HTML attribute, indicating where to display the linked resource. from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript function `document.getElementByTagName()` which allows you to target elements such as 'a'. Please see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) on how to use it.

**Edit:**

This can be followed up with using another function `setAttribute` which you can go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) to see how to use.

Answer (score 1):

regular expressions would be a over kill, and a bit difficult for JS - Beginners and PROS ;-)

for plain JS.

use as Pointy suggested

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //gets all a's
for(var idx = 0 ; idx <items.length; idx++)
{
  items[idx].target = "_self"; // sets for each a a target
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('a').attr('target','_self');
```

Using plain javascript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');  // or links[i].target = '_self';
}
```

Comment: The question is not tagged with the jQuery tag.

Comment: I don't think he is using jQuery.